# Type check that a module has specific functions?

Tags: python, protocols, python-typing

How do I check if a module implements specific functions in Python?

Say I have two modules, both implement two functions: `f` and `g`; with equal arity. However, in `mod0` `g` returns a `float` and in `mod1` `g` returns an `int`.

---

##### `mod0/__init__.py`

```
def f(a: int) -> int: return a
def g(a: int) -> float: return float(a)
```

##### `mod1/__init__.py`

```
def f(a: int) -> int: return a
def g(a: int) -> int: return a
# Or even `g = f`?
```

---

Attempt:

##### type_checker.py

```
from typing import Protocol

class ProtoFg(Protocol):
    @staticmethod
    def f(a: int) -> int: pass

    @staticmethod
    def g(a: int) -> float: pass

def check_conformance(mod: ProtoFg): pass

import mod0, mod1

check_conformance(mod0)
check_conformance(mod1)  # I want an error here
```

What I am looking for is an error similar to: "mod1 doesn't conform to ProtoFg as `mod1.f` has return type of `float` not `int`"

Related: [equivalent in TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/420#issuecomment-1030025402)

Comment: I'm suspicious you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you really trying to do? the Exception system is very effective for a try it and see approach

Comment: I am implementing `f` and `g` in many different modules and want to have some way of confirm that each implementation: has same name, takes same args + kwargs (including types), and has same return type.

Comment: is it possible to have one implementation that you import everywhere and perhaps modify the behavior of with an argument? you may really be looking for unit testing

Comment: Real-world use-case: So far I have 8 different types each with a `def parse` and `def emit`. I want confirm that they are all interchangeable. I have 99% test coverage already, happy for this type test to come at runtime or some pre lint check or whatever.

Comment: You're asking to use static type hints to do a runtime check against a prototype. It can be done because Python is a language with a *lot* of reflection support, but it won't be easy, and you'll be fighting the tooling at each turn.

Comment: Voted to reopen since you added explanations. What is the check to do, if function `f` exists, but has no/incomplete type annotations? What about parameter _names_ (for those that can be passed positional arguments)? What about generics?

Answer (score 0):

A static typing way of solving the problem of "ensuring that a signature matches `<X>`" is normally a job for a series of no-op decorators:

```
from __future__ import annotations

import collections.abc as cx
import typing as t

P = t.ParamSpec("P")
R = t.TypeVar("R")

class SignatureDispenser(t.Protocol[P, R]):
    def __call__(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        ...

    def dispense_signature(
        self: cx.Callable[P, R], f: cx.Callable[P, R], /
    ) -> cx.Callable[P, R]:
        ...

def dispense_signature(f: cx.Callable[P, R], /) -> cx.Callable[P, R]:
    return f

def as_signature_dispenser(f: cx.Callable[P, R], /) -> SignatureDispenser[P, R]:
    if not t.TYPE_CHECKING:
        f.dispense_signature = dispense_signature
    return t.cast(SignatureDispenser[P, R], f)
```

```py
@as_signature_dispenser
def f(a: int) -> int:
    return a

@f.dispense_signature  # mypy: Argument 1 to "dispense_signature" of "SignatureDispenser" has incompatible type "Callable[[int], float]"; expected "Callable[[int], int]" [arg-type]
def g(a: int) -> float:
    return float(a)
```

---

If you wanted to check this at runtime, I would opt for an [`ast.NodeVisitor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) which inspects your `f` and `g`. The following is a prototype implementation (only works for Python 3.9+):

```py
import ast
import re
from inspect import getsource
from types import ModuleType


typing_Any_pattern: re.Pattern[str] = re.compile(r"^(?:[_typing]+\.)?Any$")


class ConformanceChecker(ast.NodeVisitor):

    __f1_name: str
    __f2_name: str
    __f1_signature_str: str | None
    __f2_signature_str: str | None

    @classmethod
    def check_conformance(
        cls, module_: ModuleType, /, *, f1_name: str, f2_name: str
    ) -> bool:

        """
        Returns `True` if the signature of the function named by `f1_name` matches the
        signature named by `f2_name`, otherwise `False`.
        """

        f1_tree: ast.Module = ast.parse(getsource(getattr(module_, f1_name)))
        f2_tree: ast.Module = ast.parse(getsource(getattr(module_, f2_name)))
        checker: ConformanceChecker = cls(f1_name=f1_name, f2_name=f2_name)
        checker.visit(f1_tree)
        checker.visit(f2_tree)
        return checker.__f1_signature_str == checker.__f2_signature_str

    def __init__(self, *, f1_name: str, f2_name: str) -> None:
        self.__f1_name = f1_name
        self.__f2_name = f2_name
        self.__f1_signature_str = None
        self.__f2_signature_str = None

    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node: ast.FunctionDef) -> None:

        func_name: str = node.name
        if func_name not in (self.__f1_name, self.__f2_name):
            return

        # Wipe the function body
        node.body[:] = [ast.Expr(value=ast.Ellipsis())]

        # Uniformly name positional-only arguments
        arg_name_template: str = "__arg%d"
        arg_node: ast.arg
        for i, arg_node in enumerate(node.args.posonlyargs):
            arg_node.arg = arg_name_template % i

        self.generic_visit(node)

        if _is_typing_Any_annotation(node.returns):
            node.returns = None

        node.name = "f"  # Uniformly set function name for string comparison
        if func_name == self.__f1_name:
            self.__f1_signature_str = ast.unparse(node)
        else:
            self.__f2_signature_str = ast.unparse(node)

    def visit_arg(self, node: ast.arg) -> None:

        """
        Wipe any annotations in the signature which look like it refers to `typing.Any`
        """

        if _is_typing_Any_annotation(node.annotation):
            node.annotation = None


def _is_typing_Any_annotation(expr: ast.expr | None, /) -> bool:
    return (expr is not None) and (
        typing_Any_pattern.fullmatch(ast.unparse(expr)) is not None
    )
```

```py
>>> import mod0, mod1
>>> ConformanceChecker.check_conformance(mod0, f1_name="f", f2_name="g")
False
>>> ConformanceChecker.check_conformance(mod1, f1_name="f", f2_name="g")
True
```